synonym for "wondrous" or "awesome" but with a negative connotation?
I want a word similar to the vibes of awesome as it was used pre-contemporary times (e.g. "a terrible and awesome power"). It will be used as a contrast to the word "wondrous." Any suggestions would be fabulous.

'Similar in vibes' is a bit vague...there are lots of connotations of wondrous and awesome (both in all sorts of different directions. Did you look up synonyms of both? Can you give a situation with lots of descriptive qualifiers that might help us with what dimensions you are interested in (and want some sort of negative counterpart)? 'terrible' isn't the word you want?

"wondrous" is a very positive word, I don't think you'll find negative synonyms. But thesauruses also have antonyms, check them out. Or look for synonyms of "awful" and "terrible".

"Phenomenal cosmic powers, itty-bitty living space" (Disney). I think it's Maleficent now… 'Mighty and merciless'—that's a classic. Just dreadful is overused, like formidable, so they don't seem that bad really. Hmm, IDK. Welcome and good luck.

What is this describing? A person, natural phenomena, a god? I think "terrible" is as good as you'll get if you mean inspiring fearings of awe and terror. Most synonyms are weaker. Maybe think a bit more about exactly what reaction you are trying to describe: the different components and what urges or inclinations they inspire. (As an aside, in a non-religious world, the religious component of awe is no longer going to be relevant; people don't react to gods the way they used to.)

@StuartF "in a non-religious world" What world do you live in? There's a whole world outside your online echochamber of redditors.


(OLD) eerie adjective /ˈɪəri/ /ˈɪri/
​strange, mysterious and frightening

It is a term that seems to have become more appealing in the past few decades.

(Short Stories - 1998) An eerie wail from the canyon below the cabin frightened the visitors.
"Wondrous" can be said of melodies; so, in the universe of sounds, at least, the two words seem to be perfect opposites; this opposition is doubtless true in all sorts of contexts.

It might be what the OP is looking for, but it doesn't have the feelings of immense size and grandeur I'd associate with awe, wonder, etc.

Does fearsome fit the bill?
I am minded of the SF novel "Feersum Endjinn" by the late Iain M Banks which describes a planet spanning computer network (NOT the internet) used to upload people's mind states.

Wrong part of speech, but enormity is in the right area. Means "massive scale," but almost always used to describe something massively bad.
Or monstrous, maybe?
